# Spring WebFlux Security - Is it possible to configure multiple ServerAuthenticationEntryPoints on a SecurityWebFilterChain for different resources

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have a few different APIs in my spring webflux application that need to respond differently to failed authentication. I am trying to set different ServerAuthenticationEntryPoints for each API to handle these cases.

I found [this](https://github.com/jimonthebarn/spring-webflux-multiple-auth-mechanisms/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/localhost/playground/multi/auth/SecurityConfig.kt) example configuration that shows how to configure different AuthenticationWebFilter for different resources, which enables you to set ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler and ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler individually, however I am not sure how to configure different ServerAuthenticationEntryPoints without having completely separate SecurityWebFilterChains.

If I have to configure separate SecurityWebFilterChains, how would I do that?

My SecurityWebFilterChain is currently configured like this - unfortunately you can't set the exceptionHandling individually and the second call to authenticationEntryPoint takes precedent:

```
@Bean
fun securityWebFilterChain(
    http: ServerHttpSecurity,
    userServerAuthenticationEntryPoint: ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint,
    userAuthenticationWebFilter: AuthenticationWebFilter,
    deviceServerAuthenticationEntryPoint: ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint,
    deviceAuthenticationWebFilter: AuthenticationWebFilter,
    serverSecurityContextRepository: ServerSecurityContextRepository,
    authenticationManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager,
    serverAccessDeniedHandler: ServerAccessDeniedHandler
): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    http
        .addFilterAt(userAuthenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(userServerAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
        .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(GET, "/sign-in").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/authentication/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(GET, "/landing").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")
            .pathMatchers("/user-api/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER", "ADMIN")

    http
        .addFilterAt(deviceAuthenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(deviceServerAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
        .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/device-api/**").hasAuthority("DEVICE")

    // GLOBAL
    http
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().disable()
        .securityContextRepository(serverSecurityContextRepository)
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
        .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(serverAccessDeniedHandler)
            .and()
        .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(GET, "/webjars/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(GET, "/assets/**").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()

    return http.build()
}
```

Comment: you can add multiple entry points based on the request url patterns. See, for example, the section 3.2 of https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points

Comment: @Ritesh that would be true for a regular Spring MVC application, however the ExceptionHandlingSpec of Spring Webflux ServerHttpSecurity does not allow for  selective exception handling (as far as I can tell)

Comment: You are right, the article is not for webflux and I haven't used multiple entry points in webflux. Looking at code [ServerHttpSecurity](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/ServerHttpSecurity.java), it seems it has `defaultEntryPoints` as a list of `DelegateEntry` and it sets up a `RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint` by default.

Comment: Yeah that should work. You can restrict it with ServerWebExchangeMatchers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the default ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint is a DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint, which enables you to configure via ServerWebExchangeMatchers which actual entry point is responsible for any given ServerWebExchange. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799740/spring-webflux-security-is-it-possible-to-configure-multiple-serverauthenticat?noredirect=1#comment107580114_60799740).

Comment: could you share the code of your final solution to your question?